# Relative paths in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm not sure if this is what you call it, but how can I make something like this in PHP. mysite.com/:user/ or mysite.com/:user:/posts/:id

I want to be able to create links like this without needing to create a PHP file for each user. How is this possible using PHP?

Comment: Use a rewrite in `.htaccess` and use `$_GET` in PHP to figure out what data to use.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that's how you should do it. You need to get the user id from the url dynamically and then fetch data for this specific user and display it on a template page.